# Loading Solidworks API using Winforms under IIS

Tags: iis, windows-7, authentication, wcf

I am developing a system where user interacts with WCF Service hosted in IIS server. The WCF application then have to fire-up winform application along with some parameters. This winform application do some processing and then load a Solidworks application(software) installed on the server. This Solidworks will create some output files and put it in the share-able folder where user has a access to.

It is working fine in development environment (Visual Studio) but when I deployed it in IIS, it throws following error:

> COMException was unhandledAn unhandled exception of type
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I tried loading the WinForm using two methods:

Winform is loaded creating a instance of WinForm from WCF host

- Executable of WinForm is loaded (.EXE)
- using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

I tried following:

1. Running IIS under domain admin identity
2. Disabling UAC

Both operation failed. I tried giving AppPool "Local System“ and “Doman admin” identity but doing that It started throwing me visual studio runtime exception “ An unhandled exception of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' ". I tried converting the program into x86 too but it did not work. But when I run the application independently, it is working fine.

When I tried debugging, it is not working in this line:

```
SldWorks swApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SldWorks.Application")) as SldWorks;
```

Since it is working fine in Visual Studio environment, so I think it may be the access problem which is not letting IIS to do its work.

Comment: remember that disabling UAC would not affect an application.

Comment: It is not working in either way... just testing hit n trial. I think there is an issue with user privilege using IIS system to do operation in Server application. But could not able to solve it.